# How to save information about a function for latter use?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I'm testing a function and I want my function  to display some information about itself ONLY IF a test doesn't pass.

I don't want to alter the flow of the function while saving data for latter use.

```
function foo(input){

     //normal work of the function  

     //save the value of variable A

     //normal work of the function

     //save the value of variable B

     //normal work of the function    

}
```

This would be a test

```
fooTest(){

    var condition = foo();
    //display variable A and B depending on the value of the condition

}
```

How do I do it?

In my case, I'm testing functions and I want them to show me their value if their tests fails. If they don't fail I don't want to display information on the screen.

Comment: Use `var` (or `const` or `let`) to declare a variable, and return an object or array containing those variables at the end...? (or, return something falsey if there's an error?)

Comment: Could you add a little bit more code? I'm not sure i got your question right...

Comment: sounds like you should use the console? ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use a closure to preserve the value of variable after the function has been executed.

```js
function set(A, B) {
  // perform your operation
  let a = A;
  let b = B;
  
  // The nested scope will remember the parent's scope
  const getA = function() { return a; }
  const getB = function() { return b; }
  
  return { getA, getB };
}

var obj = set(10, 20);
console.log(obj.getA());
console.log(obj.getB());
```

Answer (score 1):

this could be a good place do use `.call()` in order to alter `this` context:

```js
function foo(input){
       //normal work of the function  
   this.A = 10;
          //normal work of the function  
   this.B = 20;
          //normal work of the function  
}

function fooTest() {
  let obj = {};
  let condition = foo.call(obj);
  console.log(obj.A, obj.B);
}

fooTest()
```